# curl vs wget（About Domain Name Resolution Process)

Tags: dns

I used the strace command to analyze the underlying implementation process of curl and wget (mainly the DNS domain name resolution part), and came to the following conclusions. I still don't understand the details, please correct me. thank!

Specific test command:

```
strace curl -v web.test.zone
strace wget web.test.zone
```

my point of view:

1. curl is achieved through the libcurl cross-platform library, for the time being do not understand curl through what method or regular acquisition of the IP address, but from the results of the strace, it does not follow the Bind DNS polling IP Address to request data.
2. Relative to curl, a wget request, it spent a lot of time on the domain name resolution, in the case of finding the hosts file without results, through a similar dig way to get all the ip address and choose one To request data, multiple tests, the result is to use different A record IP address to request data.

Comment: @melpomene strace

Comment: OK, I do not understand what you're asking here at all.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: My purpose is to understand what exactly is the difference between curl and wget in terms of domain name resolution?

Comment: Yes, but that is not a question.  You can look at the source for both commands to see how/where they handle DNS resolution.

Comment: Why did you even mention strace if your question is not about the strace results?

Comment: I am operation and maintenance, I cannot read it, so I ask @xxfelixxx

Comment: They are both open source, you can definitely read them... wget: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git  curl: https://github.com/curl/curl

Comment: No obvious answer...but this may shed some light:  https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html

Comment: If you're not a programmer and you can't read the code, what does it matter what wget and curl do internally? And why are you asking on SO, a site for programming questions?